# Transparent Networx Edge Labels

Tags: python, networkx

How to set transparent edge labels in NetworkX graph? Currently there is a white background to each label which cuts my edges and overlaps other labels

```
nx.draw(v29graph,
        nx.get_node_attributes(v29graph,'pos'),
        edge_labels=labels2
        )

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(v29graph,
                             pos=nx.get_node_attributes(v29graph,'pos'),
                             edge_labels=labels2
                             )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the bbox argument:

```
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(v29graph,
                             pos=nx.get_node_attributes(v29graph,'pos'),
                             edge_labels=labels2, 
                             bbox=dict(alpha=0)
                             )
```

More bbox style examples are [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html).